# Past tense: learned/learnt, dreamed/dreamt?

Tags: tense, past-tense, orthography

In my very first question, Carlo made an edit stating that *learnt* is a rare past tense of *learn*. I am accustomed to using *learnt* for past tense and *learned* as an adjective (as in *He is a learned scholar.*) I checked into a couple of dictionaries and they say both are valid past tenses. Do I stand a risk of not being understood if I use *learnt*?

In a similar vein, should *dreamed* be used as a past tense for *dream* instead of *dreamt*? I can't think of other such conflicts, but I guess there must be more.

Comment: Both are fine, you will be understood both ways.

Comment: To my ear, "learnt" is something someone less educated would say. As a side note, the adjective "learned scholar" is pronounced differently from "I learned my lesson": the adjective has a pronounced break into two syllables and pronounces the "e" in "ed" clearly, something like "lurn ed", while in the verb the "e" is swallowed and it's pronounced "learnd".

Comment: Not sure what's governing the choice, but I naturally use both pronunciations. I say "We learne*d* how to ..." but "I hope you learn*t* a lesson"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both are valid. *learned* is consistently more commonly used in American English:

[image]

In British English the difference has traditionally been much closer, with both being roughly equivalent, however since the 1940s, *learned* has become the dominant choice.

[image]

Comment: How do you get such nice graphs? Can't you plot without restricting to "I learnt/learned it" form? I guess there could be other patterns like *have learnt* etc where *learnt* is commoner than *learned* in BrE.

Comment: @Sultan: Here you go: http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=learnt%2C+learned&year_start=1700&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=.

Answer (score 2):

"Learned scholar" or, as another instance, "learned man" are of course the only possibilty, however in The Cambridge Guide of English Usage it is said that "In English worldwide, *learned* is the commoner form, yet there's a substantial difference between American and British."

Also, as an aside, it is worth nothing that B. A. Garner (A Dictionary of Modern American Usage) says that "To use *learnt* in American English is an affectation."

Instead, in reference to *dreamed/dreamt* The Cambridge Guide of English Usage, read that both spellings are in use, but "*dreamed* is far more common in the US."

Comment: Hmmm, so is it a BrE vs AmE thing? I come from an ex-British colony, so it tends to be closer to BrE, I guess.

Comment: Sultan, as an Italian I cannot precisely say, however Matt's Ngrams are more explicative on the BrE vs AmE matter.